# Android's memory leak because of HttpClient

Tags: android, memory-leaks, httpclient

sorry for my English.

I'm developing an Android application, consisting in various activities and a service which is activated by "main" activity. The service checks every 3 seconds (this interval is arbitrary) about active network connections into mobile phone. If there's a connection to a PC inside my local network, I then make a call to a web server there.

The problem is, I try to reach host PC through this function:

```
public boolean checkNet() {
    HttpClient client;
    HttpPost postMethod;
    HttpParams httpParams;
    URI uri;

    try {
        uri = new URI(Const.HOST_ADDRESS);
        postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
        postMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        httpParams = postMethod.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(httpParams, 512);
        HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpParams, false);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 1000);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException use) {}

    try
    {
         client.execute(postMethod);
         return true;
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

I do use this method, instead of checking WifiManager's and internal Android methods, because I have a situation like this: I can be connected to an open-encryption AP, but it has a login system (coova). Here, I can be associated (and have an IP inside LAN), but if I'm not logged I won't have access to any network, so I have to implement a "network-checking-wrapper".

So, if there was an exception in execute function because my host PC isn't reachable, DDMS will show me how heap size and allocation size will grow without control. I suspect that it's because of the sub-calls inside "execute" don't properly close obsolete references... for instance, here's a example of allocation tracker:

```
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder enlargeBuffer AbstractStringBuilder.java 99 false 
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder append0 AbstractStringBuilder.java 170 false 
java.lang.StringBuilder append StringBuilder.java 224 false 
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException <init>    HttpHostConnectException.java 48 false 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator openConnection DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java 133 false 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry open AbstractPoolEntry.java 164 false 
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter open AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java 119 false 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute DefaultRequestDirector.java 348 false
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hola pacorro, Const.HOST_ADDRESS is a downloadable file or just a web page? and do you have the last  android sdk and eclipse versions?

Answer (score 1):

Well I've already noticed one problem. You have 2 separate try-catch blocks. The first one catches a URISyntaxException. You then, in your second try-catch, call client.execute(). But if there's an exception in your first catch, client may not be instantiated and your second try-catch will result in an NPE.

Comment: Wop, that's true. I've copy-pasted the code so bad x), sorry. Supposing a reordering of the try/catch blocks, the problem takes place when "client.execute" can't reach host PC, and throws the IOExceptions, growing up the amount of memory allocated. Anyone knows how to avoid these memory leaks? Thanks!

Comment: I need to see more code and with better formatting to tell anything more

Answer (score 0):

You should close the client connection by calling client.getConnectionManager().shutdown() in a finally-Block.

Your code becomes:

```
public boolean checkNet() {
    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpPost postMethod;
    HttpParams httpParams;
    URI uri;
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        uri = new URI(Const.HOST_ADDRESS);
        postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
        postMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

        httpParams = postMethod.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 1000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(httpParams, 512);
        HttpConnectionParams.setStaleCheckingEnabled(httpParams, false);
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 1000);

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        client.execute(postMethod);
        result = true;
    } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (client != null && client.getConnectionManager() != null) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            client = null;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```